# Postgresql query to select records that do not reference another member in the group

Tags: postgresql

How would you structure the following query:

"all records with attribute=true that do not reference another member in the group"

Every record has a "parent_id" that references another record in the same table. I want to select nodes whose "parent_id" does not reference another member in the selected group. Can this be done in postgresql? How would I do it?

Comment: [edit] your question and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data. _Formatted_ text please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At a very generic level, using a subquery something like this should work:

```
SELECT *
FROM Records
WHERE parent_id NOT IN (
  SELECT id
  FROM Records
  WHERE
    attribute=TRUE
)
AND attribute=TRUE
```

But as @a_horse_with_no_name commented, if that doesn't help then you should edit question to provide more details on what you have, what you expect, and what you have tried.

Answer (score 1):

```
WITH yt AS (SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE attribute=true)
SELECT t.* FROM yt t WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM yt WHERE id = t.reference_id)
```